# How do I replace a substring with another string that contains that substring as a part of it using regex in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Suppose I have a string "03/25/93" which is in a pandas series. I want to find /93 first and then replace it with /1993. How do I go about it?

The pandas series is 
03/25/93
6/18/85
7/8/71
9/27/75
2/6/96

I want this to be
03/25/1993
6/18/1985
7/8/1971
9/27/1975
2/6/1996

```
df.str.replace(r'[/]\d{2}$', '/19??')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\1` to reference a match

```
>>> df.str.replace(r'/(\d{2})$', r'/19\1')
0    03/25/1993
1     6/18/1985
2      7/8/1971
3     9/27/1975
4      2/6/1996
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `to_datetime` with `strftime`

```
pd.to_datetime(s,format='%m/%d/%y').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
Out[937]: 
0    03/25/1993
1    06/18/1985
2    07/08/1971
3    09/27/1975
4    02/06/1996
Name: S, dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks it cleared my doubt, but I have a question what if the series also contains some data which has year as YYYY, then it would throw me an error